# Copy the field of a node referenced in a product in the product display

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

I'm using Drupal 7, [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form).

I have a node of type product display ( A ), which references a product ( B ), which references itself another node ( C ).

I create three in the air with inline entity form.

The product display ( A ) and the node ( C ) referenced by the product have 1 similar field. I would thus want to have to fill only once this field, in the form of the node ( C ).

My question: how copied automatically a field of the node ( C ) in the product display ( A )?

For example: I fill a field "thing" in the form of the node ( C ), and once published, this field appears in the node ( C ) AND in the product display ( A ).